# Powershell Script to Update DNS on multiple servers

Tags: powershell, dns

I have received the following script to update the DNS server on a windows server.  This script works great for updating one server.  I would like to have this script process a text file with a list of servers to batch update multiple servers at once.  I am thinking something like:

script.ps1 -ComputerName (Get-Content c:\serverlist.txt) -OldDns 10.0.0.1 -NewDns 10.0.0.2

This fails if there are multiple servers in the 'serverlist.txt'. My question is how to incorporate a ForEach that allows for every server in the 'serverlist.txt'

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Name of the computer to update")]
    [String]$ComputerName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="DNS server to replace")]
    [String]$OldDns,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="New DNS server setting")]
    [String]$NewDns,

    [switch]$TestMode

    )

    $niclist = Get-WmiObject -Authentication PacketIntegrity -ComputerName $ComputerName -class           Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where { $_.DnsServerSearchOrder -contains $OldDns }

if ($niclist) {
  foreach ($nic in $niclist) {
    $dns = $nic.DnsServerSearchOrder
    $dns

    $index = [array]::IndexOf($dns,$OldDns)
    $dns[$index] = $NewDns

    $dns

    $nic
    if (!$TestMode) {
      $nic.SetDnsServerSearchOrder($dns)
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `serverlist.txt` contains a list of servers where one is on each line and no headers you can just pipe the content of the file into a `ForEach-Object` loop. The `-ComputerName` will be `$_` which is the current item in the pipeline.

```
Get-Content c:\serverlist.txt | ForEach-Object{
    script.ps1 -ComputerName $_ -OldDns 10.0.0.1 -NewDns 10.0.0.2
}
```